ASP.NET не видит выданную роль
В проекте ASP.NET Core использую Microsoft Identity. Зарегистрировал пользователя в приложении через форму регистрации. Добавил роль Admin. Выдал пользователю роль через SQL запрос
DECLARE @UserId NVARCHAR(450) = 'bb233222-8e3a-4ac2-a8a3-cb8910555e38';
DECLARE @RoleId NVARCHAR(450) = '1db8f024-462c-4b06-8d42-b4ba06242db5'; 

INSERT INTO AspNetUserRoles (UserId, RoleId)
VALUES (@UserId, @RoleId);

Вот таблица ролей

Вот таблица пользователей

После выполнения SQL запроса в таблицу AspNetUserRoles доавилась запись с Id пользователя и роли. В контроллере добавил ограничение:
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;
    public AdminController(AppDbContext db)
    {
        _context = db;
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

Но переходя по адресу Admin/Index пишет, что доступ заблокирован. В чём дело?

